# MySQL proxy to replication configuration

Tags: mysql, replication, configuration, mysql-proxy

Is there any solution (say a proxy) that makes MySQL replication cluster behave like one database towards developers? Developers then won't need to worry about using master to write and slaves to read etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The new MySQL Router is one possible solution. Please take a look and let us know what you think!

I'd love to hear what features you most want in future versions.

http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-router-on-labs-the-newest-member-of-the-mysql-family/

http://mysqlhighavailability.com/easy-load-balancing-and-high-availability-using-mysql-router/

Comment: Thanks for comment, how it is different from youtube vitess?

Comment: Vitess is much more today. Vitess seems quite incredible! :)

http://vitess.io/overview/

Comment: Wow this looks awesome! Heres a good video on Vitess https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=midJ6b1LkA0

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that you would need a read/write splitting proxy. And the closest to that is the [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-proxy.html) project, but the furthest that project has is a [proof of concept](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/MySQL+Proxy+RW+Splitting)

The other, probably more desired, approach is to set up something like [Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/intro.html) behind [HAProxy](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/howtos/haproxy.html).